# Different eigenvalues of the same linear transformation according different bases

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question about linear transformation and eigenvalues.

**My question:**

Given a linear transformation $T:R^3 \to R^3$, And: $E$ is the standard basis of $R^3$, $B$ is another basis of $R^3$.

Let's denote: $A=[T]^B_B$ .

Let's assume that after gaussian elimination process on $A$ we get a matrix $M$ with one row of $0$'s, and now we calculate the eigenvalues of $M$.

- Are the eigenvalues of $M$ also the eigenvalues of the transformation $T?$

I think **yes**, because the eigenvalues don't change when you change basis, but the correct answer is **no**, can someone explain to me why?

By the way, Is it correct to say that we always must to work **only** with the standard basis of $R^3$ to find the eigenvalues of $T?$ (i.e the eigenvalues of $T$ are the roots of the caracteristic polynomial $P_A = Det(A- \lambda \cdot I)$ where $A=[T]^E_E$ , and $E$ is the **standard** basis)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Row operations will change the eigenvalues. Otherwise, every invertible matrix would only have the eigenvalue $1$, since they all can be row-reduced to the identity matrix.

Comment: In gaussian elimination you change both bases to possibly different ones (e.g. $ M = [T]^C_D$, where $C \neq D$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, I want to cite @Theo Bendit's comment and generally add: Gaussian elimination changes many properties of matrices if you're not careful with it, including eigenvalues and e.g. the determinant(at least with in the general way).

For your second question: No, the eigenvalue of the operator $T$ does not depend on the basis chosen, if you calculate the roots of $p_A$ for $A$ being a corresponding representation:

Let $A$ and $B$ be similar, that is they represent the same endomorphism w.r.t. different bases, i.e. $B=CAC^{-1}$ for some invertible $C$(which you might call the change-of-basis matrix). Then

$$B-xI=CAC^{-1}-xI=CAC^{-1}-xCIC^{-1}=C(A-xI)C^{-1}$$

Thus, as the determinant distributes over matrix multiplication, we have

$$p_B=\mathrm{det}(B-xI)=\mathrm{det}(C(A-xI)C^{-1})=\mathrm{det}(C)\cdot\mathrm{det}(A-xI)\cdot\mathrm{det}(C^{-1})=\mathrm{det}(C)\cdot\mathrm{det}(A-xI)\cdot\mathrm{det}(C)^{-1}=\mathrm{det}(A-xI)=p_A$$

The last steps follow from the elementary property of determinants for invertible matrices that $\mathrm{det}(C^{-1})=\mathrm{det}(C)^{-1}$.

**EDIT:** Note that is makes thus sense to define the characteristic polynomial for an endomorphism, i.e. defining $p_T$ as it made sense to define the determinant for endomorphisms instead of only matrices.